# sed/ awk - update characters in file

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a text file which has 5 columns separated by commas as follows

```
449,615,43,57,8
308,617,43,57,3
345,558,43,57,11
```

However a bug was identified in the code which generates these files and now i need to update the **last column** of the files such that

`if i > 10 
  i = i + 1
 else i`

I have never used awk and sed but I got the impression that this should be trivial using those tools. Can anyone give me some pointers for this? Thanks

**Edit**: Expected output for above:

```
449,615,43,57,8
308,617,43,57,3
345,558,43,57,12
```

Comment: Please post your expected output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{$NF=($NF>10?$NF+1:$NF)}1' file
```

```
$ cat file
449,615,43,57,8
308,617,43,57,3
345,558,43,57,11
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{$NF=($NF>10?$NF+1:$NF)}1' file
449,615,43,57,8
308,617,43,57,3
345,558,43,57,12
```

Can be reduced to as suggested by [anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23656661/sed-awk-update-characters-in-file/23656815#comment36335713_23656815) in comments:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} $NF>10{$NF++} 1' file
449,615,43,57,8
308,617,43,57,3
345,558,43,57,12
```

Comment: Your use of ternary makes it more explicit that the value wouldn't be changed.

Comment: Can be just: `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} $NF>10{$NF++} 1' file`

Comment: thanks figured out anyway, just didnt want to print the first line.

Comment: @dopplesoldner For that `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}NR>1{$NF=($NF>10?$NF+1:$NF);print}' file` should work. `print` inside the action block will not run for all lines unlike using `1`. `NR>1` will ensure block is only executed from second line onwards, effectively skipping first line.

Answer (score 2):

oneliner:

```
awk -F, -v OFS="," '{$NF+=$NF>10}7'
```

test

```
kent$  echo "449,615,43,57,8
308,617,43,57,3
345,558,43,57,11"|awk -F, -v OFS="," '{$NF+=$NF>10}7'   
449,615,43,57,8
308,617,43,57,3
345,558,43,57,12
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F, -v OFS="," '{if($5>10)$5=$5+1}1' input.txt
```

Output:

```
449,615,43,57,8
308,617,43,57,3
345,558,43,57,12
```